# How does changing position of format specifiers change the output of a c program?

Tags: c, pow

My code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
    int c = pow(3,2);

    printf("%f   %f   %d \n\n",pow(3,2),c,c);
    printf("%f   %d   %f \n\n",pow(3,2),c,c);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
9.000000   0.000000   4200688

9.000000   9   0.000000
```

Can anyone explain why in the first line of output instead of printing 9 (like it does in the 2nd line of output) it prints 4200688 (garbage value probably)?

Comment: Use correct format specifier. period

Comment: I have purposefully used %f as one of the format specifiers to know how exactly is this changing the output drastically in the 2 lines just by mere change in position.

Comment: Then your purpose is wrong.

Comment: My purpose is to understand how is changing position of format specifiers give inconsistent results. Shouldn't 2nd output also be 9.0000   garbage value   0.000000

Comment: Please, seek informations on the concept of "undefined behavior" in the C programming language. [This](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) might be a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

The code you mentioned having **undefined behaviour**. Read the manual page of `pow` function and check it's prototype. It says

> double pow(double x, double y);

In this statement

```
int c = pow(3,2);
```

And use correct format specifier and don't play with compiler warning while compiling  with `-Wall` flag, listen to warnings.

> 

```
warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 3 has type ‘int’ [-Werror=format=]
          printf("%f   %f   %d \n\n",pow(3,2),c,c);
```

> ```
> warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 4 has type ‘int’ [-Werror=format=]
>      printf("%f   %d   %f \n\n",pow(3,2),c,c);
> ```

From the C99 standard section 7.19.6.1

> If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding
>   conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Basically, what i infer from this discussion is that if any of my format specifier is incorrect in a line of code, then the output of my program for that piece of code can never be predicted and it is completely random.

Comment: _then the output of my program for that piece of code can never be predicted and it is completely random ?_ C standard defines that as _undefined behavior_. And practically you shouldn't write anything in your code which causes UB.

Comment: @CSEnthusiast "output of my program for that piece of code can never be predicted" --> C does not specify the output is _unpredictable_.  The behavior is _undefined_.  "output of my program for that piece of code ... is completely random" --> C does not specify the output is _random_.  The behavior is _undefined_. The point being, the result is _undefined_, not defined to be something unusual.